# Google Play store Console Release error and Warning Messages Review summary

Tags: android

Error : 
Check these errors before starting the rollout of this release. Addressing the errors on this page will ensure your existing users are able to upgrade to the latest version of your app.

Warnings :

Check these warnings before starting the rollout of this release. Addressing the warnings on this page will ensure your existing users are able to upgrade to the latest version of your app.

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate more ?

Comment: Do you have a question? Please at least paste the text of the errors and warnings so we can see what the matter is.

Comment: after successfully browse the release .apk file. I have click SAVED and REVIEW       Error : Check these errors before starting the rollout of this release. Addressing the errors on this page will ensure your existing users are able to upgrade to the latest version of your app.

Comment: Error
This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 1.

Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no relation to programming.

Comment: You'd have to add 64-bit native assembly (or remove the 32-bit native assembly)...in order to make that release. Here it's explained: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit